# Google Chart - Points with text inside and interval

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, google-visualization, scatter

I'm trying to have something like that
[image]

But for the moment I only have on serie per person and I'm not able to display the text inside the point...

[image]

I'm using a Google Scatter Chart but if you know another tool to achieve this, I'm right here :)

```
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    data.addColumn('string', 'Element');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Left');
    data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'interval'});
    data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'interval'});
    data.addColumn('number', 'Right');
    data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'interval'});
    data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'interval'});

    for( var i=0; i < dataToInsert.length; i++){
            data.addRow([
                dataToInsert[i].name,
                dataToInsert[i].L.mean,
                dataToInsert[i].L.min,
                dataToInsert[i].L.max,
                dataToInsert[i].R.mean,
                dataToInsert[i].R.min,
                dataToInsert[i].R.max 
            ]);
    }

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.setColumns([0, 1, 2,3,4, 5,6]);    

    var options = {
      pointSize: 30,
      legend: 'none',
      orientation: 'horizontal',
      vAxis: {
          minValue: -1.0,
          ticks: [-1.0, -0.8, -0.6, -0.4, -0.2, 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0]
      },
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an annotation column to display text within the point

set the following options, to remove the stem and move the text down
you can also change the text style

```
annotations: {
  stem: {
    color: 'transparent',
    length: -6
  },
  textStyle: {
    auraColor: '#ffffff',
    color: '#000000'
  }
},
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    data.addColumn('string', 'Element');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Left');
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
    data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'interval'});
    data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'interval'});
    data.addColumn('number', 'Right');
    data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'interval'});
    data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'interval'});

    data.addRows([
      ['Person A', -.2, 'L', -.6, .2, -.2, -.6, .2],
      ['Person B', -.2, 'R', -.6, .2, -.2, -.6, .2]
    ]);

    var options = {
      annotations: {
        stem: {
          color: 'transparent',
          length: -6
        },
        textStyle: {
          auraColor: '#ffffff',
          color: '#000000'
        }
      },
      pointSize: 30,
      legend: 'none',
      orientation: 'horizontal',
      vAxis: {
        minValue: -1.0,
        ticks: [-1.0, -0.8, -0.6, -0.4, -0.2, 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0]
      },
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```